# how to change boolean value thats another file

Tags: python

Im trying to make a thing that can detect whether or not a user wants their password stored for next time they run the program, The reason im using a boolean for this is so in the files that need to use the password they can check to see if storepass is True then get the pass/user from a .env if not they can get the password from the storepasswordquestion file amd use that and it wont get stored when the user closes the program.

I have a file called booleans that im using to store booleans, in it is this:

```
storepass = False
```

In a other file called storepasswordquestion i have:

```
import booleans

username = 'username'
password = 'password'

question = input('Would you like your password to be stored for use next time?') # enter y
if question == 'y':
    booleans.storepass = True
    # store password/username in .env
```

As i understand it import booleans loads the booleans file, Then i think booleans.storepass is like a variable but like a copy of the one in booleans? Because when i go on the booleans file again its still False.

Im needing to change storepass to True in the booleans file and then save it.

Comment: *Im needing to change storepass to True in the booleans file and then save it.* Exactly. Where are you stuck there?

Comment: When i run the program and enter y, then i look at the booleans file it is still False not True. Im wondering why is it not showing up in the booleans file

Comment: Source code isn't supposed to be modified by the program.  What you need here is basically a configuration file, so switch to something like [configparser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html)

Answer (score 1):

> Then i think booleans.storepass is like a variable but like a copy of the one in booleans? Because when i go on the booleans file again its still False.

That's correct - you can't change the values inside a .py file just by importing and then setting within another. py file. The standard way to manipulate files is by using some variation  of

```py
with open('boolean.py', 'w') as f: 
    f.write('storepass = False')
```

---

Personally, I really dislike writing over .py files like this; I usually save as [JSON](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_json.asp). So "boolean.json" can have just

```json
{"storepass": false}
```

and then in your python code you can (instead of importing) get it as

```py
# import json
boolean = json.load(open('boolean.json', 'r'))
```

and set `storepass` with

```py
# import json
boolean.storepass = True
with open('boolean.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(boolean, f, indent=4)
    ## NOT f.write(boolean)
```

and this  way, if there are more values in `boolean`, they'll also be preserved (as long as you don't use the variable for anything else in between...)

Comment: can you clarify how you set storepass? im struggiling to understand what it means, what is boolean doing in the f.write line? how do i make sure its changing storepass and not another boolean

Comment: @katie I'm so sorry! I should have been using `json.dump` with JSON, not `f.write`. I've corrected my answer. Anyway,  the `boolean.storepass = True` line just sets `storepass` locally, so only the code being run just then will be affected by the change; then `f.write(boolean)` saves the updated `boolean` to the 'boolean.json' file

Comment: @katie *"how do i make sure its changing storepass and not another boolean"* - as long as multiple programs aren't  writing to 'boolean.json' *at the same time*, it should be fine - when you read with `boolean = json.load(open('boolean.json', 'r'))`, you'll be getting all the booleans and [as I said] they'll be preserved **as long as you don't use the `boolean` variable for anything else in between**. with `boolean.storepass = True` you're only changing `storepass`

Answer (score 0):

You're expecting changing a variable's value to change source code. Luckily, that's not how this works!

You need to make a mental distinction between the source code that the python interpreter reads, and the values of variables.

What you need is indeed, as you say,

> Im needing to change storepass to True in the booleans file and then save it.

So, you would need to open that boooleans.py as a text file, not as a python program, read and interpret it as pairs of keys and values, modify the right one (so, `storepass` in this case), write the result back to the file. Then, the next time someone `import`s it, they would see the different setting.

This is a bad approach you've chosen:

1. Reading and parsing python files is very hard in general, because, well, Python is a programming language and can do much more than just store settings
2. The change only takes effect the next time the program is run and the settings are imported *anew*. This has no effect on other parts of an already running program. So, that's bad.

Things get a lot easier if you do two things:

1. Get rid of the idea to store settings in a Python source code file. Instead, use one of the multiple ways that python has to read structured data from a file. For your use case, usage of the `configparser` [module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html) might be easiest – a `ConfigParser` has a `read` and a `write` method, with which you can, you guessed it, read and write your config file. 
   There's multiple other modules that Python brings that can do similar things. The `json` module, for example, is a sensible way to store especially logically hierarchically structured settings. And of course, the place where you store passwords **might** also be a place where you could store settings – depending on what that is.
2. The approach of having a single module that you import (your `booleans`) is a good one, as it ensures that there's a single `booleans` that is the "source of truth" about these settings. I propose you put the configuration loading into such a single module:

```py
# this is settings.py
import json

SETTINGSFILE = "settings.json"

# when this is loaded the first time, load things from the settings file
try:
    with open(SETTINGSFILE) as sfile:
        _settings = json.load(sfile)
except FileNotFoundError:
    # no settings file yet. We'll just have empty settings
    # Saving these will create a file
    _settings = {}


def __getattr__(settingname):
    try:
        return _settings[settingname]
    except KeyError as e:
        # you could implement "default settings" by checking
        # in a default settings dictionary that you create above
        # but here, we simply say: nay, that setting doesn't yet
        # exist. Which is as good as your code would have done!
        raise AttributeError(*e.args) from e


def save():
    with open(SETTINGSFILE, "w") as sfile:
        json.dump(_settings, sfile)


def update_setting(settingname, value):
    _settings[settingname] = value
    save()
```

which you can then use like this:

```py
import settings

…

if settings.storepass:
    "Do what you want here"

…

# User said they want to change the setting:

should_we_store = (input("should we store the password? ").upper == "Y")
# this updates the setting, i.e. it's instantly visible
# in other parts of the program, and also stores the changed config
# to the settings.json file
settings.update_setting("storepass", should_we_store)
```

Answer (score -1):

You are changing the value inside the runtime, meaning you can actually change it. Meaning if you are ever trying to print out the value inside the if condition like this:

```
   booleans.storepass = True
   print(booleans.storepass)#This should return True
```

But your problem is that you are not actually changing the file. In order to change the file you should do it like this( This is the general way to write to a file with python from my research it should work in your case as well.

```
f = open("booleans.py", "w")
f.write("booleans.storepass = True")
f.close()
```

In short what you are doing is actually true for runtime, but if you want to store the result in a file this is the way to do it.

Comment: Note that your `open` will completely remove all contents from the current `booleans.py`. Which is probably not what katie had in mind.

Comment: It seemed like the OP just meant to do that so yeah you are right! And from the other answers storing as json seemed better!